# VirtualHost retornando caracteres estranhos?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, virtualhost

Preciso acessar um `virtual host` da minha máquina, e de um dispositivo `Android` (consumir uma `API`)

Quando acesso o `virtual host` com o nome que defini no meu arquivo de `hosts` "http://api.xpto/usuarios", consigo receber a resposta da `API` normalmente, porém quando tento acessar pelo `IP` da minha máquina (exemplo: http://192.168.1.106/usuarios), recebo uma resposta semelhante á essa:

```
E�_��l!/�Qe���b�����7�?�P�����@Gӗ(=�N��(����O�X��8���&M�8���z
���n֝�V�vq����$�`�^��� Y�z�
```

Meu arquivo de `hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   api.xpto
127.0.0.1   client.xpto
```

Meu virtual `host`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/api/pubic"
    ServerName api.xpto

 ErrorLog "logs/apache_error.log"
 CustomLog "logs/apache_access.log" common

    <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/api/public">
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Alguém ja passou por uma situação semelhante? Estou usando Windows 10 com `WAMP` para o `apache`.

Comment: O VirtualHost está respondendo para "api.xpto", porque quer usar o IP?

Comment: @lcssanches se eu tentar acessar por 'api.xpto' no meu dispositivo Android, conectado na mesma rede, não encontra a url, preciso apontar para o IP da minha máquina, para encontrar o virtual host.

Comment: Se você tiver acesso ao roteador, pode tentar colocar o "api.xpto" no hosts do roteador via FTP ou SSH. Verifique também o log de erros do Apache .

Comment: Isso de colocar no hosts do roteador eu faço normalmente quanto preciso  fazer esse tipo de teste.

Answer (score 2):

Isto esta parecendo resposta comprimida (provavelmente gzip), muitos navegadores suportam Gzip como resposta (praticamente todos), mas o que ocorre é que no seu caso deve estar compactando duas vezes, ou o dominio da API esta enviando compactado mesmo quando não envia o o header: `Accept-Encoding`

No httpd.conf comente a linha, assim:

```
 #LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

E reinicie o Apache

Comment: Guilherme, obrigado pela ajuda, essa linha no httpd.conf já estava comentada :(

Comment: @mauriciocaserta tem como enviar o conteudo do httpd.conf no pastebin? (é que ele é muito grande pra postar na pergunta). Estou aguardando

Comment: Segue o pastebin Guilherme https://pastebin.com/KXBwfB55

Comment: @mauriciocaserta obrigado, estou analisando e testando ;) ... pode demorar um pouco pq estou tendo que recriar o ambiente a maneira que vc fez para tentar reproduzir o problema

Comment: Sem problemas Guilherme, agradeço pela ajuda. Básicamente instalei o Wamp64 e criei o virtual host, todas configurações default (exceto o display_errors que alterei no php.ini) :)